# How to make dropdown for groups instead of checkboxes in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I have made some groups `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` through GUI in Odoo v10. These groups are shown as check-boxes on the user page.

I want that instead of these check-boxes a dropdown must be shown so that user can be assigned to only a single group i.e. a user can only be in one of the `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` groups.

How can i do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found something that will clear how drop-downs are made and how check boxes are made. This is through code not from GUI as i am still finding a solution for it.

So, drop-downs are made when each group in a category inherits some other group in same category in hierarchical manner.

So, when i wrote the following code, check-boxes were made.

```
<record id='group_category' model='ir.module.category'>
   <field name='name'>Category name</field>
</record>

<record id="group_a" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">A</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="group_category"/>
</record>

<record id="group_b" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">B</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="group_category"/>
</record>

<record id="group_c" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">C</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="group_category"/>
</record>
```

But when i wrote the following code in which one group inherits the other in a hierarchical way, drop-down was made

```
<record id='group_category' model='ir.module.category'>
   <field name='name'>Category name</field>
</record>

<record id="group_a" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">A</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="group_category"/>
</record>

<record id="group_b" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">B</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="group_category"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('module_name.group_a'))]"/>
</record>

<record id="group_c" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">C</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="group_category"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('module_name.group_b'))]"/>
</record>
```

so, this was the case when i did it. Still finding a way to do it through GUI.

Answer (score 3):

**First Create this below record through xml.**

```
<record model="ir.module.category" id="abcd_category">
    <field name="name">ABCD</field>
</record>
```

**Then Create your groups with category_id.**

```
<record id="group_a" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">A</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="abcd_category"/>
</record>

<record id="group_b" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">B</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="abcd_category"/>
</record>
......
......
```

Thats it.

**Updates :**

Add category in **manifest**.py

```
....
....
'category':'ABCD',
....
....
```

and select it from view into the Application in group formview.
[image]

Comment: I know that this will create drop-down but I've not created groups from code, I've created them through GUI and they are shown as check-boxes. I've made large amount of rules and access rights for those groups and i don't want to start over. Please suggest a way i which i can show my existing groups in drop-down.

Comment: i updated my answer. and if you want to add your groups in existing dropdown then you can select that application in group.

Comment: So, when i have to show that drop-down on user page, i can write it like this--> <field name="sel_groups_gid1_gid2" /> (gid is id of group)  ???

Comment: No it will automatically appears on the users page. no need to do any thing.

Comment: NO, not working. i've added it to an Application "Administration"  but when i open user page it says sel_groups_3_5 does not exist.

Comment: Okay then try to create new application from that dropdown. and set it in it.

Comment: Tried it. Not working. I think i have to start over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the view and specify a widget. You could try:

```
<field name="field_name" widget="selection"/>
```

or

```
<field name="field_name" widget="many2one"/>
```

I hope this help you!

Comment: Where it should be inserted?

Comment: user groups in the user form are not created from Odoo views, they're automatically created so you can't modify the field view